# Rails custom class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, class, global-variables

I'd like to create a global instance of a class that is in a file in `/lib`. I can access this class and initialize it in my controllers like so:

```
message_queue = MessageQueue.new
```

However, I would like to have a global version of this that would persist as long as the rails session is running (This is an experiment. I don't want to use a model for this).

I initialized variables in `application.rb` by doing:

```
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
```

so that they are global, to make sure the class can be found. However, I get an error: `uninitialized constant RPG::Application::MessageQueue (NameError)` when I initialize the variable.

How can I make an instance of `MessageQueue` a global variable I can access everywhere?

Comment: What is a "global instance"?

Comment: Did you include `MessageQueue` class in `application.rb`?

Answer (score 0):

First, Make sure the name of the ruby file matches the name of the class, by using the snake_case version of the classes name (your file should be called lib/message_queue.rb). This is a requirement for the rails autoloader to correctly require and load the file, and  allow you to call it easily form other classes

To make your class 'global', have a look at implementing the singleton pattern on your MessageQueue class?

Ruby has a built in module Singleton that you can include in your class, that will then ensure that only one instance of the class can be instantiated. http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/singleton/rdoc/Singleton.html

Comment: The file names match. I ended up leaving the class file in lib and just instantiating it in a file in model using it's own module 'globals' and then calling it like so: Globals::message_query_instance. Works pretty well. I might add that this only lives as long as the server is running, which was intended in my case. Thanks for the help though. I'll definitely check out the singleton module :)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone trying to get this to work, do this:

1. Create your class in a file in /lib. Make sure names match (class MessageQueue goes in file message_queue.rb).
2. Then make a file in the models folder. Call it something like globals.rb. This is where you will create the global instance of the class. Put this in the file:

   `module Globals
       instance = MessageQueue
   end`

(obviously call your class whatever you want and the instance too.

3. Access your global instance like so: `Globals::instance`
4. Take note that this instance only lives as long as your server is running. If you stop your server all of the information in the global instance will be lost.